# How to configure mariadb docker-compose file to use other port than 3306?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, containers, port

I cannot get mariadb to use another port other than 3306 when running it in a docker container using a docker-compose file.

I have already read the mariadb/docker documentation, searched online and conducted my own experiments.

1. docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
    - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=33030
    - MYSQL_UNIX_PORT=33020
    ports:
    - "33020:33020"
```

2. Dockerfile:

```
FROM: mariadb: 10.3.14
COPY mydbscript.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 33020
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

It never uses port 33020. It still uses port 3306. How can I pass the port dynamically via the docker-compose file at run-time?

Comment: It seems you have to modify the port by modify the my.cnf file.

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace the default `my.cnf` to specify a custom port for MariaDB/MySQL:

```shell
cd /where/your/docker-compose.yml/located

docker run -it mariadb cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf > my.cnf

# use any text editor your like to open my.cnf, search for "port = 3306"
# and replace it to the port you like to have.
```

Configure your docker-compose.yml like this:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ./my.cnf
      target: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
    # add your other configurations here
```

Comment: This can't be true.
` docker run --detach \
 --name myname \
 -dp 3808:3808 \
mariabd:10 \
 --port 3808`
totally works!

Answer (score 4):

The container image is statically bound to `:3306`. If you wish to change this, you'll need to build a new image and configure the database to run elsewhere.

However, Docker permits you to map (publish) this as a different port `:33020`.

The correct way to do this is to:

- docker-compose `MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3306`
- docker-compose `ports: - "33020:3306"`
- Dockerfile `EXPOSE 3306` (unchanged)

Containers (internally) will correctly reference `:3306` but externally (from the host) the database will be exposed on `:33020`.

**NB** Within docker-compose (network), other containers *must* continue to reference the database on port `:3306`.

Comment: But that's the problem that I'm trying to solve, within docker-compose (network), I need other containers to reference the database on port say 3320 (other than 3306).

Comment: Also, are there other creative ways to solve this by passing "--port=33020" to mysqld but then it complains to read documentation to learn how to run it as root but also that doesn't work and I get the error "Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist" and the online solutions didn't solve that. Example (in Docker file): CMD mysld --user mysql --port=33020

Comment: A side-effect of exposing the database to the host on `:33020` is that you can access it through this port from other containers but via the host not via the compose network name (`db`). You'd be better placed either changing the configuration of the containers that want the database on `:33020` or -- as @philip-tzou suggested by changing the `my.cnf` (`port` setting).

Answer (score 2):

@DazWilkin, @philip-tzou, of course it's possible!
How to set the port without config file is even explained in the dockerhub-page of mariadb. (https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) @Software just did the mistake of using '=' instead of ':' in the docker-compose.yml. I did it the first time too because I copied the environment variables from a docker run bash file.

This docker-compose.yml (with .env File) works for me to set both, internal and external port of my mariaDB service:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.8
    container_name: ${db_containername}
    environment:
      MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
      MARIADB_DATABASE: ${db_database}
      MARIADB_USER: ${db_user}
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: ${db_password}
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: ${db_port_internal}
      MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE: 1
      MYSQL_UNIX_PORT: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
      MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '${db_port_external}:${db_port_internal}'
    expose:
      - ${db_port_external}
    volumes:
      - 'database_data:/var/lib/mysql'
```

Comment: `MYSQL_TCP_PORT` that's the env var I need. Thanks.

Comment: @lesca You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

### This is how you can set a different port for your mariadb inside the container

#### 1. Create a my.cnf file inside the same directory as you dockerfile

write this inside the my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
port = 33020
```

#### 2. Add the cnf file to the dockerfile & edit the EXPOSE

Add this line of code to your docker file

```
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And make sure to change the external exposed port to the one you want to use e.i

```
EXPOSE 33020
```

#### 3. Make sure to change the port in the docker-compose.yml file

```
ports:
- "33020:33020"
```

You can now connect to your database in either the terminal using the `docker exec -it {databasename} mysql -u root -p` or in something like mysql workbench by setting the ip: localhost and the port to 33020

Hope this helps.